# WMI_EXPORTER textfile_inputs not working?

Tags: wmi, prometheus, exporter

I've been trying to setup text files input for [WMI_EXPORTER](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter).

It is saying it's successfully imported the text file, but I can't see it in the metrics when going to `http://localhost:9182/metrics`.

I can't find much information about how to view the data, do I need to go to another URL?

> DEBU[0006] collector textfile succeeded after 0.000000s.  source="exporter.go:218"

See above for the debug information for the file collector.

Comment: What is the content of the textfile ? Did you check that `wmi_textfile_scrape_error` is 0 ?

Comment: yeah thats the only message i got. no errors...

Comment: Did you use `--collector.textfile.directory` parameter or do you use the default value `C:\Program Files\wmi_exporter\textfile_inputs` ?

Comment: i was using the default directory. even when specifying it does work 

Comment: What is the file extension of your prom file ? Only files with the extension .prom are read. If windows is configured to hide the extension, you may be missing that point.

Comment: ive renamed to .prom and now its throwing up errors when importing it advising invalid metric name and also unexpected end of input stream. These are both erroring after testing with a txt file that has 2 lines :(

Comment: That's good. Show us a sample of the file content. Note that the last line should also have a line feed. For the file to be valid

Comment: the file literally had "test" in it. What is a line feed? I have not seen any of this information online.

Comment: ive just tried to use the below

test
\n

this is what comes back  text format parsing error in line 1: expected float as value, got ""

Comment: It means the last metric line should end with a end-of-line (in your editor, you should have an empty line at the end).

Comment: I have done this, would it be possible to show me a sample file so i can understand it better.

Comment: See the link about text format in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first steps to have wmi_exporter ingest Prometheus textfile are:

- place the files in the directory configured in parameter `--collector.textfile.directory` or use the default directory `C:\Program Files\wmi_exporter\textfile_inputs`
- name the files with `.prom` extension, otherwise they are ignored

Then, the content of the textfiles must comply with the [text format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#text-format-details):

- the `.prom` file must end with an empty line feed.
- the metrics are written one metric per line with format `metric_name value` or `metric_name{labelname1="labelvalue1"[,... other labels]} value` with

  - metric name must match the regex `[a-zA-Z_:][a-zA-Z0-9_:]*`
  - label name must match the regex `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` (label name with `__` prefix are reserved).
- lines starting with a `#` are comments, with two special comment formats:

  - `# HELP metric_name A long description` provides the metric description
  - `# TYPE metric_name <type>` provides the [metric type](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#metric-types)

The metric name and the optional labels (key and value) uniquely defines a metric which means that:

- all metrics of the same name should have the same label set
- the same metric (same name and labels) should not appear twice in the file
- the promfile importer checks that HELP and TYPE comments are always the same if they are repeated (for coherency).

Additionally, the metrics name and labels should follow the [best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#metric-and-label-naming)

**A minimal promfile content** would be:

```
my_sample_metric 1
```

*(don't forget the empty line at the end)*

A more complete example is provided in the [text format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#text-format-details) page.